# Installation gets stuck after selecting option

Tags: system-installation

When I try to install Ubuntu, after I select install, the monitor displays this:

```
Booting 'Install Ubuntu'

(hd0,1)

Filesystem type is ntfs, partition type 0x7

[Linux-bzImage, setup=0x4200, size=0x583c58]

[Linux-initrd @ 0x7ec26000, 0x13c9603 bytes]
```

Previously I tried to install with two monitors (a HDMI TV and a VGA monitor), with the VGA monitor being the one I currently use. When I did this, the HDMI TV worked, with the VGA monitor displaying the same as it is now. FYI: No, I don't have the HDMI TV to use

I also have a NVIDIA GTX 750 Ti as a graphics card, which plugs into the monitor with a DVI adapter

**UPDATE:** I plugged the VGA cable into the motherboard so I can install Ubuntu, but I would still like to be able to use my (fairly expensive) GPU

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* :/  Please visit the [Ask Ubuntu Tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) to better understand how this site works, as it is quite different from a forum...

Comment: @Fabby I'm sorry, It's just I'm a little desperate to get Ubuntu working. But basically, I want to be able to plug my monitor into my graphics card, and it to be able to display the GUI in the same way that it does if I plug it in to the motherboard. My problem is, that right now the graphics card doesn't display the GUI, so I can't play any games at a reasonable framerate. I've heard I can fix it with NVIDIA drivers, but every time I install it, there is either no effect, or it breaks Ubuntu

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some frustration I have fixed my problem. All I needed to do was install an older driver (340) because the newer one had a bug. For those who are also in the same position I was in, I used [this guide](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/install-latest-nvidia-340-46-via-ppa/) to install the driver.